# Reusing login session and cookies for subsequent requests in Python using requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, request, session-cookies

I have successfully implemented a login process using the Python requests library, where I authenticate with a server and receive a valid session and cookies in the response. However, I'm facing challenges when trying to reuse this login session and cookies for subsequent requests within the same session.

The issue I'm encountering is that when I try to use the same session and cookies for subsequent requests, the cookies seem to be empty or the session expires, leading to unexpected results. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
import requests

login_url = "https://app.intouchemr.com/ite/login"

payload = f'username={username}&password={password}'

session = requests.Session()


login_headers = {
    'authority': 'app.intouchemr.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,'
              'application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'origin': 'https://app.intouchemr.com',
    'referer': 'https://app.intouchemr.com/ite/login.xhtml?loginerror=1&error=zero',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


response = session.post(login_url, headers=login_headers, data=payload)


if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Login successful")
    print(response.cookies)
    url = "https://app.intouchemr.com/ite/secure/Patients/patientsList.xhtml"
    payload = ""
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    session.headers.update(headers)

    response = session.post(url, data=payload)
    print(response.text)
else:
    print("Login failed")
```

**After successfully logging in, the print(response.cookies) statement returns <RequestsCookieJar[]>, indicating empty cookies. As a result, subsequent requests using the same session and cookies do not work as expected.**

My goal is to reuse the login session and cookies for subsequent requests to maintain the authenticated state throughout the session. How can I effectively use the same login session and cookies for subsequent requests?

Any guidance or insights on properly reusing the login session and cookies would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!